# How to scroll when navigating a ul with keyboard javascript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll, html-lists

I implemented a function to navigate through a list and scroll when I hit the last item visible in the list, this is my code so far:

```
const arrowNavigation = (
    e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    if (selectedCountry.current) console.log(selectedCountry.current.last());
    if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      if (selectedCountryIndex < autoCompleteSuggestions.length - 1)
        setSelectedCountryIndex(selectedCountryIndex + 1);
      if (selectedCountryIndex > 3)
        if (selectedCountry.current && dataList.current) {
          console.log(selectedCountry.current.offsetHeight);
          dataList.current.scrollTop +=
            selectedCountry.current.offsetHeight;
        }
    } else if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      if (selectedCountryIndex - 1 >= 0)
        setSelectedCountryIndex(selectedCountryIndex - 1);
      if (selectedCountryIndex > 3)
        if (selectedCountry.current && dataList.current) {
          dataList.current.scrollTop -=
            selectedCountry.current.offsetHeight;
        }
    } else if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      if (textInput.current)
        textInput.current.value =
          autoCompleteSuggestions[selectedCountryIndex];
      setInputValue(autoCompleteSuggestions[selectedCountryIndex]);
    }
  };
```

This is the view currently:
[image]

To explain the code:

dataList is the ul.

selectedCountry is the li element that I am currently on.

selectedCountryIndex is the index of element that I am currently on.

autoCompleteSuggestions is a list of country suggestions based on the input I've given.

So my approach was to wait till selectedCountryIndex is at a certain point to start scrolling but this is really just a hardcoded solution if my list view has more visible items it wouldn't really work, is there a way to know how many visible items the ul has? or maybe know the position of the visible items in the ul (like first last and so on..).

[image]

Also, as you can see in the gif when I scroll down it works perfectly, but when I scroll up, I start seeing the next element little by little, I am not sure why that's happening, so if you have any idea about that as well let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const ul = document.getElementById('dataList');
  let li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li')[mIndex + 1];
  li?.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'end',
  }); // my pseudocode using element ids
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it and let you know!